# SSRS 2005 Sorting

Tags: visual-studio, reporting, reporting-services

A quick question for someone, hopefully!

In my .rdl file source I can see the tag "< sorting >"

Where abouts in the GUI (I'm using Visual Studio) can this property be set?

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Comment: Are you asking about interactive sorting or static sorting?

Comment: Hello,

I'm asking where in the gui do you set the property which affects the contents of the < sorting > tag which can viewed in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, click on the table so that it is selected. Then at the top right, right click to get table properties. Hey presto... there is a sorting tab!